# how to make this animation move on chrome even after adding @webkit?

Tags: css

I'm on chrome and have added `@-webkit-keyframes` and `-webkit-animation` property. The div doesnt move left. what went wrong?

```css
.oneDiv{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-animation: oneAnimation 5s;
  animation: oneAnimation 5s;
}




@-webkit-keyframes oneAnimation {
  0%   {left: 0px; background: red;}
  25%  {left: 100px; background: blue;}
  50%  {left: 100px; background: yellow;}
  75%  {left: 40px; background: green;}
  100% {left: 0px; background: red;}
}


@keyframes oneAnimation{
  0%   {left: 0px; background: red;}
  25%  {left: 100px; background: blue;}
  50%  {left: 100px; background: yellow;}
  75%  {left: 40px; background: green;}
  100% {left: 0px; background: red;}
}
```

```html
<div class="oneDiv"></div>
```

Comment: You'll need to set [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for `left` to work.

Comment: Also -webkit- prefix for animation  are no longer needed for today's webkit browser . for the position, pick any but static , strat with relative if that's fine. else use transform:translate().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `left` css property wont work on block elements. Changing the `.oneDiv` to have `position: absolute;` or `position: relative` seems to do the trick!

```css
.oneDiv{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-animation: oneAnimation 5s;
  animation: oneAnimation 5s;
  position: absolute;
}




@-webkit-keyframes oneAnimation {
  0%   {left: 0px; background: red;}
  25%  {left: 100px; background: blue;}
  50%  {left: 100px; background: yellow;}
  75%  {left: 40px; background: green;}
  100% {left: 0px; background: red;}
}


@keyframes oneAnimation{
  0%   {left: 0px; background: red;}
  25%  {left: 100px; background: blue;}
  50%  {left: 100px; background: yellow;}
  75%  {left: 40px; background: green;}
  100% {left: 0px; background: red;}
}
```

```html
<div class="oneDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I would use relative, so it remains in the flow ;)

Comment: Yes relative would also work!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use position static as well, in a similar way as mentioned above!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33029141)